# Android EditText: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: getChars (0 ... 16) ends beyond length 15

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I'm developing an app for Android using Android Studio. I have to let the user insert a text into an EditText with a maximum length. For this aim I have employed a lengthFilter passing to it the maximum length.

Here the declaration:

```
etMessage.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxMessageLength)});
```

In another thread I execute the following code:

```
while (!startEncoding){

    final String temp = etMessage.getText().toString();

    if (!(Comparison.equals(temp))) {
        Comparison = temp;
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvNumCharacters.setText(Integer.toString(maxMessageLength - etMessage.length()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

These last lines just show into a TextView (tvNumCharacters) the residual numbers of characters the user can input when the string inside the EditText (temp) is different from the string previously contained in the EditText (Compare).

The Problem is: when the user deletes some characters (independetly from the actual length of the already inserted string) the following exception is raised:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8364
Process: com.user.steganography, PID: 12057
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: getChars (0 ... 16) ends beyond length 15
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1090)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:972)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.toString(SpannableStringBuilder.java:994)
at com.user.steganography.Coding.checkTextLength(Coding.java:111)
at com.user.steganography.Coding.access$000(Coding.java:19)
at com.user.steganography.Coding$2.run(Coding.java:84)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Sometimes it crashes when deleting just one character, other only when deleting more characters.

This happens when `etMessage.getText().toString()` is recalled.

Could anyone suggest me a solution for this problem? I have already tried to change the attribute `android:inputType` but it still not work.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the approach for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner so if you have any suggestions I will really appreciate it

Comment: Look into `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` for EditText. This is not a heavy enough load on the device to want to move it to a background thread.

Comment: That's the solution! Thank you very much!!

Comment: The correct way to mark a question as solved is to answer and accept down below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION]

By using `addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)` the problem of threading was avoided and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have threading issues.  The contents of etMessage are changed before they are read the second time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I havent't understood what you mean: if i comment the handler the problem persists. How can I improve the code in order to overcome the problem?

Comment: I think tvNumCharacters.setText(Integer.toString(maxMessageLength - etMessage.length())); should be something like tvNumCharacters.setText(Integer.toString(maxMessageLength - temp.length()));

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately... Commenting the entire handler section (and so leaving just `final String temp = etMessage.getText().toString();` inside the while), the app still crashes when deleting some chars from the keyboard